# How to use new programs/applications without internet or root access?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, compiling

I am given a computer without root or internet access. (It is running Ubuntu 18.04) 
It seems to be installed with minimal installation and it seem to lack most of the common application-level package managers.

I can use flash drives to download and move anything that I want from my normal computer  to this machine, but the problem is always at installing/building it with these limitations. I either need root access to install something in root directories, or internet access to install some dependencies, or a lot of the times both.

The programs that I'm trying to use are usually meant to be installed via apt, or are scripts (which their interpreter and application-level package manager isn't installed), or are yet-to-be-compiled codes (which their build system isn't installed).

Is there anyway for me to use any program/application other than the ones pre-installed on this machine?

I have seen a lot of answers for only one of these limitations (no root access or no internet access). But I have to deal with both of these limitations and I can't find any help/solution online.

Comment: boot a "live" linux from a USB - then tinker with the innards of the installed linux

Comment: @JaromandaX I have to return the machine to it's owner after some time, I don't think they would approve of me tinkering with their installed linux. If they were fine with it they would simply just give me the sudo password instead.

Comment: sudo password would be the same as the password you use to log in

Comment: @JaromandaX depends on the configuration of `sudo`, it could also take `root`s password but it's of course worth a try